# Have vim complete #include lines

Tags: vim, autocomplete

Say you're editing a .c file, and you're on a line like:

```
#include {here}
```

and you press the tab key, is there a way to have it complete all the header files that are relative to the current directory and also all the systemwide header files such as stdio.h and stdlib.h?

Comment: Note also that CoC+ccls (I haven't tried with clangd) permit to complete various things, and among them the names of included files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, `:help compl-filename` says:

> Note: the 'path' option is not used here (yet).

But how about hacking together our own custom completion based on the examples found in Vim's documentation?

Here is what we are going to work with, found under `:help complete-functions`:

```
fun! CompleteMonths(findstart, base)
    if a:findstart
        " locate the start of the word
        let line = getline('.')
        let start = col('.') - 1
        while start > 0 && line[start - 1] =~ '\a'
            let start -= 1
        endwhile
        return start
    else
        " find months matching with "a:base"
        let res = []
        for m in split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec")
            if m =~ '^' . a:base
                call add(res, m)
            endif
        endfor
       return res
    endif
endfun
set completefunc=CompleteMonths
```

Here is a high-level explanation of how it works:

> The function is called in two different ways:
>
> - First the function is called to find the start of the text to be completed.
> - Later the function is called to actually find the matches.

In the code, the first part of the conditional handles the first call, it doesn't need to be changed. It is the second part, which handles the second call, that we are going to change. Since we want files in `&path`, we can use `:help globpath()` with the given base to list matching files under `&path` and `:help fnamemodify()` to only return the filename:

```
function! CompleteFromPath(findstart, base)
    if a:findstart
        " locate the start of the word
        let line = getline('.')
        let start = col('.') - 1
        while start > 0 && line[start - 1] =~ '\a'
            let start -= 1
        endwhile
        return start
    else
        return globpath(&path, a:base . '*.h', 0, 1)
            \ ->map({ idx, val -> fnamemodify(val, ':t') })
    endif
endfunction
set completefunc=CompleteFromPath
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: omg this is really good, I'll need to tweak it to include the surrounding bits, "..." for files in the current directory and <...> for files in the system directories.