# How to Traverse directories with vim file name completion in insert mode with path environment variables?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

Say I have a path like,

`$MYDIR/filename.txt`

How do I auto-complete the filename?

`CTRL-X CTRL-F` in insert mode only does this for absolute and relative paths. Is there a way to make vim consider the environment variables too?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327156/have-vim-complete-include-lines/66330348#66330348.

Comment: Also https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21218/filter-file-completion-list

Comment: I am able to use environmental variables and `<c-x><c-f>` without issue. I did `$VIMRUNTIME/<c-x><c-f>`. It does expand the environmental variable though. I imagine you need to check `'isfname'` to make sure `$` is present. There maybe other settings/options I am unaware of though. I am using Vim 8.2.1719

Comment: @PeterRincker `$VIMRUNTIME` expands to an absolute path. If `$MYDIR` expands to something that is neither absolute nor relative to the working directory, then there is no completion. Moreover, `$VIMRUNTIME` is expanded, which may or may not be what OP wants.

Comment: @raveen-kumar, could you describe the expected behaviour and give us more context, like the value of `$MYDIR`, the current working directory, the relationship between `$MYDIR` and the current buffer, etc.?

Comment: @romainl I can confirm that the Environment variable expansion works. I don't know why it did not work last time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works by default in vim..

Answer (score 0):

I think two options must be considered:

```
 " it allows vim to search everywhere in your folder
 :set path+=.,**    
 " it allows you temporarelly leve the current file even if it is not saved yet
 :set hidden
```